# Looking for words similar to "lagging" and "ahead of"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

In computer networking, assume that I'm waiting for packets which are ordered by sequence number. First I get sequence number 1, and then 2, then 3 …

Assume that I now have 99 packets and I'm waiting for the packet with sequence number 100.
If I get a packet with sequence number 50, since I have received it already, I say
this packet is an *obsolete* packet or *lagging* packet. But if I get a packet with sequence number 200, how do I describe it? An *advanced* packet?

Comment: They are simply called "**out of order packets**". If you get a packet that has already been received, it's a "**redundant packet**". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet for more information. A nework that cannot guarantee services is called "**unreliable**". Transport layer protocols correct for this.

Comment: Why the down vote? Any difficulty in understanding it?

Comment: By the way, it would if at all, be an *advance* packet, without the **d**.

Comment: I'm not at all versed in computer networking, but my inclination would be to call it a "premature" or "early" packet.

Comment: @Jim I agree with *redundant packet* as being the normal way of calling such packets for us. But that's a combined term which accounts for both the scenarios: when an already received packet comes back again, or even when a packet comes in way ahead of its sequence. I guess, the OP is trying to get a specific word. <br> But yes, for me, while talking in the engineering field, I would go ahead and just call them redundant packets.

Comment: "Advance" or "early" seem to make sense to me, as I feel, for some, that "premature" has a connotation of it arriving _too_ early (unless this is the case). I'm not familiar with networking, but, semantically, I wonder if no obvious term exists because it would be inaccurate to call packet 200 early.  If packets were being sent in sequence and 200 came after 99, it seems more to me that 100-199 were all lagging.  That is, I assume packets are supposed to travel as fast as they can and thus they can't travel faster than they should.  Note I mean this as speculation not as a statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *a premature packet* would probably be the best way to describe this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy! this reminds me of school again. Anyways, for the packets that are yet to arrive or the packets that are to come we can call them a number of things like: (some have examples depicting its usage)

1. [successive packets](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/successive?q=successive): usage [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_delay_variation).
2. [leading packets](http://thesaurus.com/browse/trailing?s=t): usage [example.](http://books.google.com/books?id=t60_xTVn15gC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=networks%20leading%20and%20trailing%20packets&source=bl&ots=8NwgrDauA0&sig=OacFcXI7aWpjYAGccF5AN_efZbY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=92dfUfTMJ6WD0QH464GoDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=networks%20leading%20and%20trailing%20packets&f=false)
3. [Subsequent packets](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subsequent?q=subsequent): Do a ctrl+f for *subsequent* and you'll find its usage [example](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ping.html).
   Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364045/tiny-packets-with-tcp-a-bad-idea-better-with-udp).

I used to just call them all (leading or trailing) as *out of sync* bits. I had one more commonly used word on the tip of my tongue. Will come back and post it here, if I remember it.